# Configuring SPI on PIC16LF1827

Tags: pic, spi

Has anyone encountered problems getting SPI up and running on a PIC? I'm using a PIC16LF1827 and am trying to output data via SPI to what will eventually be an LCD graphics screen. The PIC will be the Master.

Attached is a picture of what I'm seeing on the SPI port pins (via Salae Logic Analyzer). I figure there must be something wrong in either my configuration or there is some flag or bit that needs to be checked before I can write successfully to SSP1BUF register.

[image: SPI outputs]

Also this is source code that generated the waveforms.

```
        /************************

This is a module to initialize the PIC16LF1827 to communicate with
the Nokia 5110 graphical LCD screen. I'm going to draw something. 

author: Osagie Igbeare

8/7/2014

*************************/

/**************** Header Files *********************/

#include "BitDefs.h"
//#include <htc.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include "pic.h"
#include "chip_select.h"



/***************** Configuration Macros ***************/

//__CONFIG(FCMEN_OFF & IESO_OFF & FOSC_LP & WDTE_OFF & MCLRE_ON & PWRTE_OFF & BOREN_OFF
//      & LVP_ON & WRT_OFF & CPD_OFF & CP_OFF);

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = LP        // Oscillator Selection (LP Oscillator, Low-power crystal connected between OSC1 and OSC2 pins)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Memory Code Protection (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset disabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = ON    // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is enabled on the CLKOUT pin)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Switchover (Internal/External Switchover mode is disabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is disabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config PLLEN = OFF      // PLL Enable (4x PLL enabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON     // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (Low-voltage programming enabled)


/***************** # Defines *****************/
#define lcd_data BIT3HI
#define lcd_command BIT3LO
#define hangTime 1000

/*************** module level variables ************/

static char counter; 
int x;
int i = 0;
char dummy;
static char LCD_Init[6]; 



/******* Function Prototypes ***************/

void InitPorts(void);
void InitTimers(void);
void InitInterrupts(void);
void InitComm(void);
void NokiaInit(void);
void Delay(int waitTime); 
void SightPin_B0(void);



/******* Acutal Functions ****************/

void InitPorts()
{

    ANSELA = 0x00;          // Port A pins are digital
    ANSELB = 0x00;          // Port B pins are digital

    TRISA = 0b11111010;     // 1 - input, 0 - output, RA2, RA0 are outputs
    TRISB = 0b10000010;     // 1 - input, 0 - output, RB0, RB2 - RB6 is an output

    PORTA = 0b11111111;         // initialize LED to OFF
    PORTB = 0b11111111;


    //OSCCON = 0x68;
    APFCON0 = 0x00;

}

void InitTimers()
{

    T2CON = 0b01111110;     // Fosc / (4 instruct * 16 prescale * 16 postscale * 60 PR2) = 65 Hz
    PR2 = 1;
}

void InitInterrupts()
{

    PIE1 = 0b00000010;      // Enable TMR2IE, interrupt when Timer 2 matches PR2
                            // Enable SSP1IE, interrupt for MSSP1 (aka SPI1)
                            // Bit 3 high - enable MSSP interrupt   
    INTCON = 0b11000000;    // Enable GIE, Enable PEIE

}


void InitComm()
{
    // setup SPI-1 (aka SSP) to communicate with Nokia LCD screen

    SSP1ADD = 0;                                    // Baud Rate = Fosc / ((SSP1ADD + 1)(4))
                            // since Fosc = 4 MHz, Baud Rate = 1 MHz
                            // since SSP1ADD = 0 is not supported same timing is achieved
                            // by setting bits <3:0> of SSPM all to 0's (see below)

    SSP1STATbits.SMP = 0;               // data on rising edge, data @ middle
    SSP1CON1bits.WCOL = 0;              // no collision
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPOV = 0;             // no overflow


    SSP1CON1bits.CKP = 1;               // idle high 
    SSP1STATbits.CKE = 1;               // sample even edges 

    SSP1CON1bits.SSPM3 =  0;            // Set LF1827 as Master, clock rate Fosc / 4
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPM2 = 0;
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPM1 = 0; 
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPM0 = 0;

        SSP1CON1bits.SSPEN = 1;             // SSP Enable

}

void NokiaInit()
{

    i = 0; 
    // LCD_Init array populated with initialization sequence

    LCD_Init[0] = 0x21;         // tell LCD extended commands to 
    LCD_Init[1] = 0xB0;         // set LCD Vop (contrast) ** parameter to mess with if screen doesn't display **** 
    LCD_Init[2] = 0x04;         // set temp coefficient
    LCD_Init[3] = 0x13;         // LCD Bias mode 1:48 (if not working, try 0x13)
    LCD_Init[4] = 0x20;         // back to regular commands
    LCD_Init[5] = 0x0C;         // enable normal display (dark on light), horiz addressing


    // initialization sequence for the PCD8544 driver on the Nokia LCD
    // beginning with RESET 

    /*
    PORTA &= BIT0LO;
    Delay(hangTime); 
    PORTA |= BIT0HI;
    */

    PORTB &= lcd_command;           // tell LCD commands are coming



    PORTB &= BIT5LO;            // lower SCE line to begin transmission

    //SightPin_B0();

        //PIR1bits.SSP1IF = 0;

        SSP1CON1bits.WCOL = 0; 

    SSP1BUF =  0xC3;

        while (!SSP1STATbits.BF);               // wait for buffer to be full

        /*
        if(SSP1CON1bits.WCOL == 0)
    {
        SSP1BUF = 0xC3;
    }
        */





    /* 
    SSP1BUF = 0x21;         // tell LCD extended commands to 
    SSP1BUF = 0xB0;         
    SSP1BUF = 0x04;         
    SSP1BUF = 0x13;             

    SSP1BUF = 0x20;         
    SSP1BUF = 0x0C; 
    */          

    PORTB |= BIT5HI;        // raising SCE line at the end of transmission0
}

void interrupt ISR()
{
    counter++; 
    if (TMR2IF)
    {
        if ((counter % 2) != 0)
        {
            PORTA |= BIT2HI;
            //PORTB &= BIT6LO;

        }
        else 
        {
            PORTA &= BIT2LO;
            //PORTB |= BIT6HI;
            counter = 0; 
        }

        TMR2IF = 0;     // clears the TIMR2IF (timer 2 interrupt flag)

    }
    /*
    if (SSP1IF)
    {   

        if (i < 6)
        {
            SSP1BUF = LCD_Init[i];
            i++;
            SightPin_B0();
        }

        SSP1BUF = LCD_Init[i];

        SSP1IF = 0; 

    }
    */

    return; 

}

void Delay(int waitTime)
{
    x = 0;
    while(x < waitTime)
    {
        x += 1;
    }
}

/***********************************************************/
/******************** Debugging Library ********************/

void SightPin_B0(void)
{
    // toggles pin B0 for debugging purposes
    if ((PORTB & BIT0HI) == BIT0HI)
    {
        PORTB &= BIT0LO;

    }
    else
    {
        PORTB |= BIT0HI; 
    }

}


/********************************************************/
/******** Main - which actually runs the code ***********/
/********************************************************/

void main ()
{

    // Initializing PIC16LF1827
    InitPorts();
```

Thanks for your help.

**RESOLUTION:**

So it seems that I had to wait for the Buffer Full Flag to be clear before raising the SS line to signal the end of a transmission.

If anyone has experience with Salae, you know they usually display the hex values of the bytes that are on the line. I was wondering why this wasn't the case here. It turns out that when enabling the SPI under "Analyzers" all 4 lines need to be dedicated to some channel, even if that one channel isn't being used (in my case, I wasn't using the MISO line since I intend for one way communication with a graphic LCD screen - Nokia 5110 with PCD8544 driver to be more exact).

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly the problem is you're experiencing. It's not clear from the logic analyzer alone.

Comment: MOSI and CLOCK look plausible, assuming you intended the clock to be high between bytes.  The diagram is too squished to tell if there are 8 clock pulses in each of the three bytes, but what we can see seems to be in order.  It would help to look at slave select too.  You haven't defined what your remaining lines are, so they are just noise that we can only ignore.

Comment: @OlinLathrop you're correct the other lines are just noise. That enable was the SS line, after talking with microchip, I was able to remedy the SS line issue by waiting until the Buffer full flag was clear before raising it - apparently this is necessary even when only transmitting.

Comment: @DanLaks I was wondering why the Analyzer wasn't recognizing any of the bytes on the MOSI line. Since the post, I've discovered that all 4 lines need to be assigned to a channel when using SPI under "Analyzers", otherwise the values won't show up.

Comment: I don't understand how you can expect it to work differently.  When you write to SPI data register, that only *start* the bus byte exchange.  You have to make sure the byte is done being sent before deasserting SS.  This is only on the last byte of the sequence.  For other bytes you only need to check that the buffer is ready for a new byte, and write one when it is.  SPI is so easy to do in firmware that I usually skip using the peripheral if the PIC is only the master.  Being a slave is a whole different matter, and dedicated hardware for that is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

As I've just done this I feel I should add to Olin's answer with some code. SPI is terribly simple but you do have to wait for it! There are also application notes warning you to read the buffer and, if you don't need the byte, don't use it. I believe that might be PIC dependent.

Before this code starts, I clear any possible errors by clearing SSPOV, WCOL and BF. Just in case!

```
    ; == This is an SPI transmit from FSR1 ==
    ;
    ;   nbytes contains the 8 bit number of bytes to send
    ;   We are not interested in the received bytes and we
    ;   poll until completion (SPI is very fast)

Xfer_transmit:

    banksel     SSP1BUF
    moviw       FSR1++
    movwf       SSP1BUF                 ; ssp1buf = *fsr1++

    ifbclr      SSP1STAT, BF            ; Wait for transfer to complete
      jmp       $-1

    movf        SSP1BUF, W              ; Clear BF. Discard data.

    banksel     nbytes
    decfsz      nbytes, F
      jmp       Xfer_transmit

    ; Transmit complete.
```